# C++ NIM game logical error

Tags: c++, setter

**display not working properly,  will not show the board properly when implemented within the main.

> > This is updated code for the NIM game<<
> >     Winner function and display function not working properly**
> >     I need help figuring out how to get the display function working properly please.

```
class cboard{

    private:
int sticks;
bool player;

    public:
//default constructor
cboard(){sticks=10;}

//constructor with parameter given
cboard(int x){sticks=x;}

//stick set
void setstick(int m){sticks-=m;}

//display stick getter
int get_sticks(){return sticks;}

//display function, a.k.a baord getter
void displaycboard ()
{for (int i=sticks; i>0; i--)
    {cout<<"| ";}
    cout<<endl;}

};
```

Comment: `goto BAD;` Oh the irony...

Comment: meant to show versatility lmao

Comment: So your problem here is that you can't have more than one answer to the same question, but I'll take a look and add additional points to the bottom of my answer

Comment: I think you want a `if... else` rather than `if(){}` followed by `take=rand()...` every time. It's also now impossible to judge why your results aren't as expected, because you've removed the `main()` function which is presumably calling all of these functions you've written!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in `displaycboard()`. The `for` loop needs to change a variable that isn't `sticks`.

Change your code to read

```
for (int i = sticks; i > 0; i--)
{
...
}
```

and it works fine. It still outputs two lines due to being repeatedly called in the loop though (since the loop iterates, and calls with the same number of sticks at the end of the first, beginning of the second loop).

Edit: With reference to a comment about your `goto BAD`, you could replace that with something like

```
int s = 0;
while (s <= 2)
{
    cout << "How many... greater than 2" << endl;
    cin >> s;
}
```

Second edit: Your comment reflects that you know this isn't safe, but you can deal with the non-int values using a stringstream (`#include <sstream>`), and

```
std::string instring;

    while (s <= 2)
    {
    cout<<"How many sticks would you like to play with this game (Greater than 2): ";
    getline(cin, instring);
    stringstream(instring) >> s;
    }
```

This will allow you to enter something like `1.25` and have the program ask for a new value, or `5.25` and have it play with 5 sticks. Note that `5.99` still gives 5 sticks...

Comment: Incidentally, giving a non-integer value really messes up this program, in both implementations

Comment: AHHHHH i see exactly what i did wrong.  Thank you so much, especially since this project is due by the end of the night.  In reference to your comment, i just wanted to show my professor versatility, i realize it isnt practical or safe.

Comment: I am new to this forum, i have just completed my project and what you said did in fact work.  But now i am having the same exact problem and was wondering if you could assist me in my query.  Im willing to up your rep by as much as i can when am qualified to

Comment: What's the new problem? Also, asking/answering questions gives rep, so just keep asking/answering, supposedly it works out in the end! :)

Comment: Well, if this question is solved, you shouldn't keep going here. Perhaps a new question (if it's a different issue?) and link to it here (in comments)

Answer (score 1):

Your `displaycboard()` is directly modifying the class member variable `sticks`, reducing it to 0 after the first `displaycboard()`.  The next time you call `displaycboard()`, the member variable `sticks` is at 0, meaning there is nothing to print out.